# How to use AJAX in side AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following JavaScript to get the HTML.

```
$('#myHref').change(function() {
    var value = $('#myHref').val();
    $.get('get_project.php',{id:value},function(data) { 
        $('#projectDetail').html(data);
        $('#projectDetail').fadeIn('slow');
    }); 
});
```

I use some html in `get_project.php` as follow:

```
<select name="sn_id" id="sn_id" >
    <option>Data1</option>
    <option>Data2</option>
    .....
</select>
```

I want to select menu and get returned on the basis of it. So again I add the following JavaScript to get value according to selected `sn_id`:

```
$('#sn_id').change(function() {
    var value = $('#sn_id').val();
    $.get('calculate_invest.php',{id:value},function(data) { 
        $('#show_me').html(data); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I don't really know what your question is, can you make it clearer?

Comment: Yes. Question Is Unclear. Please Explain Bit More.

Comment: does your 2nd piece of code which handles the change of dropdown not work?

Comment: I use ajax and return select menus. Again I want to select the returned select menu and return somethng according to menu which was returned

Comment: @Mike 2nd piece of code i.e html will be returned and displayed. again I want to select that returned select menu and get some results

Comment: @yank if you want to bind another ajax call then it should be bind on success of first ajax.

Comment: @JiteshNK ok, that may be also another way,  I manage to solve it. Thnks

Comment: So, what was wrong? Your comments do not make sense.

Comment: try $('#sn_id').on('change', function(){ some code });

Comment: Thnks guys, I get my answer. I just need to use different id. For eg. If i use <div `id="my_menu"></div>` to display the menu. I have to use `$('#my_menu').change(function(){}` not `$('#sn_id').change(function(){}`

Comment: @EagleEye Plz look my comment again. Thnks for reminding me.

Comment: If you don't want downvotes, please don't use "txtspk" in your questions, answers, or comments. It really isn't too much to ask to expand `dnt` into `don't` etc. You're making work for editors at present.

Answer (score 0):

you are dynamically adding your "select" , then you need to add the event in the document, like this:

```
$(document).on('change','#sn_id', function() {
    var value = $('#sn_id').val();
    $.get('calculate_invest.php',{id:value},function(data) { 
        $('#show_me').html(data); 
    }); 
});
```